# Docker: Connect to Wildfly server from outside

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly

I am having trouble connecting to a Wildfly server running in a Docker Desktop container. My Dockerfile is like so:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:9.0.1.Final
COPY ./standalone-template.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
COPY ./MyApplication.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/MyApplication.war
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

The server seems to start successfully, and at the end of the output from the CMD running `docker run -it mydockerimage` I see this output:

```
19:20:21,260 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /MyApplication
19:20:21,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "MyApplication.war" (runtime-name : "MyApplication.war")
19:20:21,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0061: Http management interface listening on https://0.0.0.0:9993/management
19:20:21,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0052: Admin console listening on https://0.0.0.0:9993
```

However, I am not able to connect to the server's admin console or the application from my machine's browser, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. When I modify the docker run command to be `docker run -it -p 9993:9993 mydockerimage` I am able to connect to the admin console, but I can't do the same for the application itself. Normally for an https Wildfly server I wouldn't use any port when trying to connect through the browser, but trying to do `https://localhost/MyApplication` fails.

What should I change to allow connection to the "MyApplication" web context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include port 8080 in run command

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 9993:9993 mydockerimage
```

and access your application at not `https://localhost/MyApplication` but at `https://localhost:8080/MyApplication`, or any other port that you choose in `-p 8080:8080` for host port.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I tried what you suggested and receive ```ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED```.

Comment: Which ports are configured for http/https in the AS?  Maybe those are not 8080/8443, may be 80 and 443.  You can list them by doing `netstat -tlnp` inside the container, or by looking up the serevr configuration. Update `-p` with those ports in run command.

Comment: I've got 80, 443, 9993, and 8009, and 443 worked when added to -p! This does solve my question, but do you know if this would need to be added to docker commands every time? Or is there a way to bake it into the Dockerfile somehow?

Comment: Ports are not available in `Dockerfile`, build time artefact. You can save the command as `make` target in `Makefile`, or create a docker-compose file wherein you can use [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)